# Dog and cat eating each other's food, what should I do?

Tags: cats, dogs, diet

Both my dog (2 years old, female) and my cat (6 months old, male) eat premium-class dry pet food (Hill's).

For some reason, the cat prefers the dog's food -- even though it's harder to eat (bigger pieces). [I'd rather they stick to their own food](https://pets.stackexchange.com/a/18795/13343).

I only give the dog her food at given times -- but even then, the cat gets there before she does and starts eating, I have to physically take him away so she can eat.

Any ideas for how to prevent them from eating each other's food are welcome.

Comment: Is it just the cat eating the dog's food or does the dog also steal the cat's food. If the latter is also applicable, can you detail what deterrents you've implemented?

Comment: @Pyrotechnical I give them both food at the same time. The cat goes straight to eating the dog's food, no matter how many times I take him away from it. He doesn't eat his own food, and if I leave it there, the dog eats it at some point later. The cat is not hungry after eating a few bites from the dog's food.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question about deterrents. The only way I found to prevent the cat from eating the dog's food is feeding the dog inside a large flight cage that I have, but I'd rather not do it. Likewise, the only way I found to prevent the dog from eating the cat's food is placing his bowl under a cabinet that has legs tall enough to allow the cat to be there but not to the dog.