My puppy is addicted to junk food
So, I’m kind of a pushover and will let my dog (a 4 month old teacup Chiweenie) eat my food. Just small amounts. However, now that’s all she wants it seems and worse, she started to love sweets and will try to steal cookies, get candy wrappers, etc. In addition to this, she eats a lot of cat food because my roommate keeps it out all the time for her cats (and this won’t change).
I’m worried about her nutrition, and more so her teeth.
I plan on getting a toothbrush and toothpaste for her. I do try to feed her high quality dog food when I can, but I’m not in a position to leave our kibble out. (I know this sounds strange, but I live in a tiny house with an curtained doorframe in the yard of my friends trailer. If I left out food it would attract bugs, because it’s essentially outdoors. She gets the cat food kibble because she goes inside my friends trailer all the time.)
But I feed her wet food and I try to feed her the better brands. Occasionally I will make her a meal of rice and chicken (long grain white rice and shredded chicken). I am  considering making her a meal of brown rice, shredded beef or chicken, and bone broth multiple times a week, occasionally mixed with various dog food “supplements”.
However this doesn’t stop the issue that she’s addicted to sweets. She loves ice cream, even chocolate occasionally if she can get a hold of it (never very much, I’m talking like licking the inside of a candy wrapper). And will the cat food harm her!?
What’s the best way to feed her? Is there a certain schedule that I should stick to? Can I give her sweets if for a dog? What about human food in general (not the sweet kind). How bad is it really for them?
Most of all, how do I eat food in front of her without feeling like a mean person for not sharing with her!? lol. Please help!

What does human food causes in dogs; https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/26168/is-cheap-human-food-for-street-dogs-good-for-their-health

Each time you eat, think about the health of your dog and that you want him healthy and long at your side. Find some treat/food healthy for him and eat together with him, but both the correct food

Shouldn't the same answer apply as our own addictions to junk food? Don't offer it. Keep it out if the house. Let the dieter whine about it until they resign themselves to eating better. Unlike yourself or your kids, the pup can't go out and buy their own candy; if you don't give it to them on demand, they will eventually learn that they can't demand.

I'd say trying to get your dog to 'fixed' feeding times, and the VERY VERY occasional treat  is the best strategy. A lot of human foods are unexpectedly toxic. Also, if your dog has too much sweet food, teeth can rot, or your dog could develop diabetes  just like with humans, and its a pain to deal with.

Human food often contains too much salt and/or sugar (even for humans), so don't give it to animals

Your scope (number of questions) is very wide here; here's an answer to the question about the cat food: https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/18774/dog-eats-the-cat-food-cat-eats-the-dog-food

Wow.  Lots to unpack here.

she started to LOVE sweets and will try to steal cookies, get candy wrappers, etc. In addition to this she eats a lot of cat food

Sweets are bad for a dog or cat. They are full of refined sugar and maybe chocolate or Xylitol.  Dogs already get a lot of carbs they don't need from commercial dog food. Anything that is plant based (i.e. grains, sweet potato etc.) have a high level of carbs that dogs do not need to survive. They can get more species appropriate energy from protein they eat.
The main reason dogs don't get cat food, is that it often has a higher fat content. In theory it should contain more meat than dog food — but without regulation to include percentages of meat, you will never know. They also boost Taurine amino acid in cat food (because cats need this) — but dogs should get an adequate amount from the meat they eat.

I’m worried about her nutrition, and more so her teeth.  […] I plan on getting a toothbrush and toothpaste for her.

AFFCO only requires 18% protein for regular dogs, 22% for puppies.  They will get this in puppy commercial dog food, but because it's mostly plant, it isn't bio available and they are more likely to get access to maybe 70% of that protein, if they are lucky.
Vets recommend toothbrush training a dog when young, but you are then supposed to do it daily.  That is why dried meat treats that are 100% meat, clean the teeth without depositing carb crumbs on their teeth, and they get the protein their bodies need to grow.

meal of rice and chicken (long grain white rice and shredded chicken). I am considering making her a meal of brown rice, shredded beef or chicken, and bone broth multiple times a week, occasionally mixed with various dog food “supplements”.

Wholegrain rice and 2/3rds chicken is a more appropriate meal than commercial dog food — particularly if you are including bone broth.  But they might also need something like raw chicken necks or wings for the calcium/ phosphorous.  If you give your dog varied meat and secreting organ based foods, then they don't need "supplements".  Commercial dog food mostly has added minerals and vitamins because the bulk of it is plant based, and they don't have a high enough level to reach the AFFCO high levels (for minerals and vitamins) —  but feeding meat, and meat treats will cover all of the protein (amino acid) requirements,  and bones for the calcium.
It sounds like you are going to have to make your puppy go close to 'cold turkey'.  Weaning them off lollies and sugar is more about how you feel about it, than what they need.
If they eat their kibble or wet food too fast, use one of the dimpled maze kinds of dog bowls where they really have to get their tongue into the grooves to get all of the food out.  That will also create a  puzzle to stimulate their mind.
Most people just feed their dogs kibble or wet canned food. if you feed them a few meals that are meat based throughout the week, that will definitely benefit them (and protein will make them feel more full).
Good luck with it. I can see you are dedicated to your dog.
Perhaps reading the other side of dog feeding might help you balance what you do such as this:  https://www.facebook.com/groups/rawfeeding101learntofeedraw
